# Does the Bi-Laplacian generate an analytic semigroup?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, laplacian, semigroup-of-operators

It i well-known that the Laplace operator generate an analytic semigroup for example in $L^2(\Omega)$ on nice domains $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Now does also the Bi-Laplacian generate an analytic semigroup or at least a strongly continuous one? Can you provide references?

Comment: This might be related, and possibly contains some relevant references: https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.08364

Comment: You should specify the boundary conditions to get a clear answer.

Comment: @S.Maths omogeous Dirichlet boundary conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the bi-Laplacian with Dirichlet boundary conditions generates an analytic semigroup on $L^p(\Omega), \; p\in (1,\infty)$. For $p=2$, you can show that the operator is self-adjoint. A general result was proved in **Theorem 5.6, pp. 189** in

> Hiroki Tanabe, Functional Analytic Methods for Partial Differential Equations, vol 204 of Monographs and Textbooks in Pure and Applied Mathematics, New York, 1997.